# Extract bounding edges from set of edges

Tags: graph, graphics, tree, geospatial, computational-geometry

I have a CAD drawing and I need to find all the perimeter or bounding edges to create an enclosing polyline from them.
I have used some brute force techniques but they require the drawing file to be opened in an editor (AutoCAD) to use selection tools etc, I'd like to avoid this if I can by using something like a BSP tree, KD-Tree, R-Tree or similar. I'd also like to keep this independent of any particular CAD system. The KD and R trees seem like they have the most promise so far.
Are there any particular graph algorithms or other tree structures I could consider?

There are 2 caveats but not show stoppers, some of the edges can be crossing and I would need to choose and possible break/split these if they make up part of the final perimeter. There are also some gaps at end points due to conversion software but these can be handled with a given tolerance.

Basically I need to take all lines from the drawing file (any curves have been segmented into lines), create 'edges' and put them into a tree/graph and then process/traverse it to find bounding edges.
I can then use the resulting edges to create the bounding linework.

Thanks for any suggestions.

(EDIT)
I've stumbled onto the spatial hash grid, it allows me to create predefined selections of a set of neighbouring edges to process, the grid also gives me a direction to process. I can also create smaller grids within these larger cells to fine tune selections for smaller edges if needed.
It seems like my best option at this point.

Answer (score 1):

The basic way this is done is to treat your lines as a subdivision of the plane into regions, splitting edges at intersections to ensure that each edge bounds exactly two regions (or one, in the case of curves with a naked endpoint). I would normally do this with a sweep-line algorithm similar to the [Vatti clipping algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vatti_clipping_algorithm). Acceleration structures like kD-trees and R-trees can help speed this up (not a sweep-line, but other clipping/subdivision algorithms), but they aren't the most important part. Once you've got the subdivision, just keep only those edges which border the unbounded region. If you want to remove naked curves extending outward from the boundary, then keep only those edges which border both the unbounded region and a different region.

I would not suggest coding this up from scratch. CGAL should have everything you need.

Comment: Thanks, I'm thinking this would assume the lines are facing 'out' of the unbounded region. This is not the case as the lines do not have a normal, only start and end which could have been drawn either way.
I'll take a look at the Vatti algo and digest your suggestion a bit further. 
Thanks!

Comment: Limes do not need to be oriented for this to work. They separate regions regardless of orientation.

Comment: Ok, after a bit of study I think Vatti might be a bit of overkill and difficult to implement as you pointed out (i.e. use a lib). I have all I need to traverse a set of lines and stay on the 'outside' of the set, my biggest issue is narrowing the selection to nearest neighbours to avoid processing every edge against each other or the scan lines. A small/average sample is around 25k lines, that's a lot of regions to create! 
I've updated the OP with some further thought using spatial grids.

Thanks again :)

Comment: Actually, it’s a fairly easy algorithm to implement. But you’re not hearing me. No algorithm is easier to implement than *using an existing implementation*. And I guarantee you, the code you will write will be slower and have have more bugs than CGAL.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, it is appreciated and it pointed me in the right direction. CGAL is good but I'd rather avoid C++ and try shoehorning it in with the other API's.

I'm basing my algorithm on the Bentley-Ottmann algorithm which is pretty simple, I need to store computed edges instead of points of intersection. I've written most of the data structures over a few hours, now I need to fine tune the 'events' as I line sweep the points.

Results so far using C#, more than happy with that for my application:
  903989 points processed...
  RunTime (min:secs.msecs): 00:02.45

cheers.